# Sending MultipartFile and JSON object with POST method

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman

I have the POST method with him I want to send an image and a JSON object. 
This is my method:

```
 @PostMapping("/saveCategory")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void createCategory( @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam("id") CategoryModel s) {
        System.out.println(s);

        String fileName = fileStorageService.storeFile(file);

        String fileDownloadUri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath().path("/downloadFile/")
                .path(fileName).toUriString();
    //  category.setImage_path(fileName);

        //this.categoryRepository.save(category);

         /*return new UploadFileResponse(fileName, fileDownloadUri,
        file.getContentType(), file.getSize());*/

    }
```

This is my post request from POSTMAN:-
[image]

I can not understand where is my problem, with POSTMAN request or my method?

This is my CategoryModel:

```
 @Entity
@Table(name = "Category")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
public class CategoryModel {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    //@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String category_name;
    private String category_description;
    private String image_path;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "category")
    private Set<ProductModel> category;
```

Comment: Show your class category model

Comment: Error seems to be because of category_name variable, spring expects it to be of Long but you are sending as string from postman. Please check how have you used category_name in your code.

Comment: You can see my categoryModel. My category_name  variable is String but my id is Long.

Answer (score 0):

The response error says that you are expecting an id of type CategoryModel, but you are sending an id of type String.

The FormData is mainly intended for use in sending form data. This has the restriction that you can only send files or strings as a key/value pair and not objects.

You can rename the id to categoryName and put "ziska111" as a value. In the method, replace `@RequestParam("id") CategoryModel s` with `@RequestParam("categoryName") String categoryName`.